# C++/cli error C4368: cannot define 'list' as a member of managed 'queue': mixed types are not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer, dining-philosopher

I'm totally new to c++ Gui..
i'm trying to make a simple windows form to draw on my dining philosophers semaphore solution

my semaphore header file

```
ref class sema4
{
 private:
  int sem_value;
  queue Waiting_List;
 public:
  sema4();
  void wait(HANDLE h);
  void signal();
};
```

My semaphore cpp

```
sema4::sema4()
{
 sem_value=1;
}

//suspend the thread 
void sema4::wait(HANDLE h)
{
 sem_value = sem_value - 1;
 if (sem_value < 0)
  {
    Waiting_List.enqueue(h);
    SuspendThread(h);
  }
}

//Resume the thread
void sema4::signal()
{
  sem_value = sem_value + 1;
  if (sem_value <= 0)
   {
    ResumeThread(Waiting_List.dequeue());
   }
}
```

My queue header file

```
ref class queue
{
 private:
  HANDLE list[20];
  int front;
  int rear;

 public:
  queue();
  void enqueue(HANDLE x);
  HANDLE dequeue();
  bool isempty();
  bool isfull();
 };
```

the queue CPP

```
queue::queue()
{
  front=-1;
  rear=-1;
}


void queue::enqueue(HANDLE x)
{
  if(isfull())
   {
     cout<<"queue is full";
   }
 else
  {
    if(front==-1)
            front=0;

    rear=(rear+1)%20;
    list[rear]=x;
  }
} 


bool queue::isfull(){
  if (front==(rear+1)%20)
        return true;
  return false;
}


HANDLE queue::dequeue(){
  if(isempty())
   {
      cout<<"queue is empty";
      return NULL;
   }
  else
   {
    HANDLE x =alist[front];
    if (front==rear)
        front=rear=-1;
    else front = (front + 1) % 20;
   }
 }

bool queue::isempty()
{
  if((front == rear) && (rear == -1))
  {
    return true;
  }
return false;
}
```

i keep getting the error C4368: cannot define 'list' as a member of managed 'queue': mixed types are not supported
and i have no real experience using c++ windows forms

Answer (score 2):

### The simple answer

The compile error you're getting is because `queue` is a managed type. Managed types need to be declared with a `^`, and created using `gcnew`.

### The more complex answer

What you're writing isn't C++ code. This is a language called C++/CLI, which is intended for interop between .Net managed languages such as C# and unmanaged languages such as C and C++. As such, it has all of the complexities of C++, all of the complexities of C#, and a few extra of its own.

While you're just learning, please pick one or the other, and go with that. If you want to write managed code, learn C#. If you want to write unmanaged code, learn C++. Don't tackle C++/CLI while you're still learning.